# Use generated json object instead d3.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I missed a lot of time that to resolve this problem but unlucky. I know how to render d3 tree with external file, but how to do that with generated object. I'm getting Json object thru this code:

```
   $.when($.getJSON('data/clinical.json'), $.getJSON('data/industry.json'))
        .then(function (a, b) {
            return $.extend(a[0], b[0]);
        })
        .then(function (data) {
           var json = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log('['+ json +']');
```

and have added json to d3.json

```
treeJSON = d3.json(json, function (error, treeData) {
```

so whole part of code looks like:

```
function load() {

    $.when($.getJSON('data/clinical.json'), $.getJSON('data/industry.json'))
        .then(function (a, b) {
            return $.extend(a[0], b[0]);
        })
        .then(function (data) {
           var json = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log('['+ json +']');

// Get JSON data
    treeJSON = d3.json(json, function (error, treeData) {
```

the most interesting part is that console log self defined such as right string:

```
[{"text":"Alas","icon":"icons/tree.png","children":[{"text":"CDISC","children":[{"text":"SDTM","children":[{"text":"SDTM 3.1.1","icon":"icons/file.png"},{"text":"SDTM 3.1.3","icon":"icons/file.png"},{"text":"SDTM 3.2","icon":"icons/file.png"}]},{"text":"ADaM"},{"text":"CDASH"}]},{"text":"CDISC"},{"text":"BRIDG"}]}]
```

but I'm still getting an error:

```
GET http://localhost:63342/testMerg/%7B%22text%22:%22Alas%22,%22icon%22:%22…SH%22%7D]%7D,%7B%22text%22:%22CDISC%22%7D,%7B%22text%22:%22BRIDG%22%7D]%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried to use string method from some example which I found somewhere here:

```
      .then(function (data) {
           var json = JSON.stringify(data);

// Get JSON data
    treeData = JSON.parse( data );
```

but got an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

so I give up... could anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because `data` is an Object and your trying to parse the object. But `JSON.parse` function expects a string as the parameter.

You can either directly assign `treeData = data`. (No need for parsing).

Or else you should try stringifying the object and then parse the stringified json.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
treeData = JSON.parse(json);
```

```js
var data = {"text":"Alas","icon":"icons/tree.png","children":[{"text":"CDISC","children":[{"text":"SDTM","children":[{"text":"SDTM 3.1.1","icon":"icons/file.png"},{"text":"SDTM 3.1.3","icon":"icons/file.png"},{"text":"SDTM 3.2","icon":"icons/file.png"}]},{"text":"ADaM"},{"text":"CDASH"}]},{"text":"CDISC"},{"text":"BRIDG"}]};

//treeData = data;

json = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

Comment: it's the same method which I did and have got the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: No. note that you were trying `JSON.parse(data);` instead of `JSON.parse(json);`

Comment: you've been almost right, instead var json, I've used just root =, and then treeData = JSON.parse(root)